Convert vector to matrix by blocks -reshape
just a quick question
I am struggling in R to convert a list of numbers to a matrix that has a fixed number of rows
and the numbers are placed in triplets (blocks of 3 rows) at a time
The elements are numbers but I will just show the position where I want them to be placed.
e.g. for 3 rows
1   2   3   10  11  12 
4   5   6   13  14  15 
7   8   9   16  17  18 
for 4 rows
1   2    3  13  14  15
4   5    6  16  17  18 
7   8    9  19  20  21 
10  11  12  22  23  24 
3 rows:
1   2   3    10   11    12      19  20  21     28   29  30   
4   5   6    13   14    15      22  23  24     31   32  33 
7   8   9    16   17    18      25  26  27     34   35  36 
Thanks!
tried many different ways and packages but no luck

Use gl to create a vector consisting of 1,1,1,2,2,2, etc. up to nr,nr,nr (where nr is the desired number of rows).  split will repeat it to the length of the input so split the input by that and rbind the resulting list components together. No packages are used.
f <- function(x, nr) do.call("rbind", split(x, gl(nr, 3)))

# tests

f(1:18, 3)
##   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## 1    1    2    3   10   11   12
## 2    4    5    6   13   14   15
## 3    7    8    9   16   17   18

f(1:24, 4)
##   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## 1    1    2    3   13   14   15
## 2    4    5    6   16   17   18
## 3    7    8    9   19   20   21
## 4   10   11   12   22   23   24

f(1:36, 3)
##   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
## 1    1    2    3   10   11   12   19   20   21    28    29    30
## 2    4    5    6   13   14   15   22   23   24    31    32    33
## 3    7    8    9   16   17   18   25   26   27    34    35    36

This variation also works:
f2 <- function(x, nr) t(simplify2array(split(x, gl(nr, 3))))


You can try this.
> fn <- \(x, n) {
+   array(x, c(n, 3, length(x)/(3*n))) |> aperm(c(2, 1, 3)) |> matrix(3)
+ }
> 
> fn(1:18, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3   10   11   12
[2,]    4    5    6   13   14   15
[3,]    7    8    9   16   17   18
> fn(1:24, 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2    3    4   13   14   15   16
[2,]    5    6    7    8   17   18   19   20
[3,]    9   10   11   12   21   22   23   24
> fn(1:36, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    2    3   10   11   12   19   20   21    28    29    30
[2,]    4    5    6   13   14   15   22   23   24    31    32    33
[3,]    7    8    9   16   17   18   25   26   27    34    35    36
> fn(rep(LETTERS, 2), 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "M"  "N"  "O"  "P"  "Y"  "Z"   "A"   "B"   "K"   "L"   "M"   "N"  
[2,] "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "Q"  "R"  "S"  "T"  "C"  "D"   "E"   "F"   "O"   "P"   "Q"   "R"  
[3,] "I"  "J"  "K"  "L"  "U"  "V"  "W"  "X"  "G"  "H"   "I"   "J"   "S"   "T"   "U"   "V" 

Maybe you just want
> fn2 <- \(n.rows=1, n.cols=1, n.slice=1) {
+   x <- seq_len(n.rows*n.cols*n.slice)
+   if (n.slice == 1) {
+     matrix(x, n.rows, n.cols, byrow=TRUE)
+   } else {
+     array(x, c(n.cols, n.rows, n.slice)) |> aperm(c(2, 1, 3)) |> matrix(n.rows)
+   }
+ }
> fn2(0, 0, 0)
<0 x 0 matrix>
> fn2(1)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
> fn2(4, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
> fn2(3, 3, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3   10   11   12
[2,]    4    5    6   13   14   15
[3,]    7    8    9   16   17   18
> fn2(4, 3, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    2    3   13   14   15   25   26   27
[2,]    4    5    6   16   17   18   28   29   30
[3,]    7    8    9   19   20   21   31   32   33
[4,]   10   11   12   22   23   24   34   35   36
> fn2(3, 3, 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    2    3   10   11   12   19   20   21    28    29    30
[2,]    4    5    6   13   14   15   22   23   24    31    32    33
[3,]    7    8    9   16   17   18   25   26   27    34    35    36


A couple generalized solutions:
matblock1 <- function(x, n, m, k) {
  matrix(x[sequence(rep(n, m*k), sequence(rep(m, k), seq(1, n*m*k, n*m)), m)], n)
}

matblock2 <- function(x, n, m, k) {
  matrix(aperm(array(x, c(m, n, k)), c(2:1, 3L)), n)
}

Testing:
n <- 3; m <- 3; k <- 2 # rows; columns per block; number of blocks
matblock1(1:(n*m*k), n, m, k)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1    2    3   10   11   12
#> [2,]    4    5    6   13   14   15
#> [3,]    7    8    9   16   17   18
matblock2(1:(n*m*k), n, m, k)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1    2    3   10   11   12
#> [2,]    4    5    6   13   14   15
#> [3,]    7    8    9   16   17   18

n <- 4; m <- 3; k <- 2
matblock1(1:(n*m*k), n, m, k)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1    2    3   13   14   15
#> [2,]    4    5    6   16   17   18
#> [3,]    7    8    9   19   20   21
#> [4,]   10   11   12   22   23   24
matblock2(1:(n*m*k), n, m, k)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1    2    3   13   14   15
#> [2,]    4    5    6   16   17   18
#> [3,]    7    8    9   19   20   21
#> [4,]   10   11   12   22   23   24

n <- 3; m <- 3; k <- 4
matblock1(1:(n*m*k), n, m, k)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#> [1,]    1    2    3   10   11   12   19   20   21    28    29    30
#> [2,]    4    5    6   13   14   15   22   23   24    31    32    33
#> [3,]    7    8    9   16   17   18   25   26   27    34    35    36
matblock2(1:(n*m*k), n, m, k)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#> [1,]    1    2    3   10   11   12   19   20   21    28    29    30
#> [2,]    4    5    6   13   14   15   22   23   24    31    32    33
#> [3,]    7    8    9   16   17   18   25   26   27    34    35    36

Benchmarking:
n <- 30; m <- 40; k <- 50; x <- runif(n*m*k)
bench::mark(
  matblock1 = matblock1(x, n, m, k),
  matblock2 = matblock2(x, n, m, k)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 matblock1     240µs    354µs     2627.    1.18MB     59.6
#> 2 matblock2     238µs    485µs     2066.    1.37MB     62.0

